# Adding options to existing drop down list using WatiN

Tags: c#, html, watin

I need to automate an existing webpage and add certain information into it. However, one of the information field required is a drop down box which is blank and there are no options in it. Unlike other drop down list where I can use `browser.SelectList(Find.ById("")).SelectByValue("");` to obtained the desired value automatically.

Hence, I would like to ask if these two methods can be done at my current situation:

1. Is there any method where I can forcefully push in an option into the drop down list, so that I am able to select it using the code mention above.
2. The drop box list is initially blank, but values can be added through a separate Window, but I am unsure if WatiN can be used to jump between different Windows.

I am using WatiN for this project. If there is any links which can help me through, please do point me to the right direction.

Comment: Is this related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392685/watin-add-a-new-option-to-a-selectlist

Comment: If there are no options in the drop down list, why are you trying to select anything? I think we need some more context about this specific test. It sounds like the user workflow is: 1) Fill the drop down list with values from a pop up window; 2) Use the dropdown list for something.

Comment: This StackOverflow question describes how to interact with pop up windows using WatiN: [WatiN testing of a popup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523142/watin-testing-of-a-popup)

Comment: Thanks Greg, its exactly as you said, the drop down list will only show value after filling a pop up window. The link you shown me helps, but I've used `Find.ByTitle` instead. 

Thank you.